# React-native error while importing another files

Tags: react-native, import

I am just importing my files from a custom created  folder component to App.js file and import key in not working on manually created files while working on other imports on React and React native.
I am making an application of React-Native using Expo Cli[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRYAt.png)

```
import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import test from './component/test';   // This line is producing error

export default function App() {

 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <test/>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({`enter code here`

container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

});
```

TEST COMPONENT :----

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Login js file</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

PLEASE VISIT CODE IMAGE line 3 is causing error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRYAt.png

Comment: can you share your test component so that we can check , or share your code in an expo snack so that we can see.

Comment: share you error stack here

Comment: Do you have exported the file first?

Comment: Try to rename a file and function in the capital letters Test.js, const Test=()=>{}

Comment: No it didn't  export it first

Comment: how to share error stack

Comment: Cannot see the error image in the description.

Comment: sir it is on the top in description in There is last option Code IMAGE